# Multiplying square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify the following types of question:

$ \sqrt{x^2+5} \times \sqrt{x^2+20}$

Do I need to get both answer out of their roots first or not? This is how I would do it:

$ \sqrt{x^2+5} \times \sqrt{x^2+20} =  x^2 + x\sqrt{20} + x\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{100}$ but I'm very certain this isn't the correct way.

Comment: Just a brief note about vocabulary: $\sqrt{x^2 + 5} \cdot \sqrt{x^2 + 20}$ can not be _solved_, since there is no equation.  Presumably, you mean to be ask how to _simplify_ the expression.

Comment: @JavaMan Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive real $a,b,c,d$

$\sqrt{a+b}\cdot\sqrt{c+d}=\sqrt{(a+b)(c+d)}=\sqrt{ac+ad+bc+bd}$ which is $\ne \sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{ad}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{bd}$

Comment: That sounds more logical than what I thought of

Comment: @Birdistheword, observe that the last inequality always holds for positive real numbers.